# Magento 2: `magento app:config:import` doesn't import system configuration

Tags: magento2, import, configuration, system-config

I'd like to import system config through the `app:config:import` command.

I have update `app/etc/config.php` file with described `customer/captch/enable` config path:

```
<?php return array (
  'system' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'customer' =>
      array (
        'captcha' =>
        array (
          'enable' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  'modules' =>
  array (
    'Magento_Store' => 1,
    'Magento_Directory' => 1,
    'Magento_Eav' => 1,
    'Magento_Backend' => 1,
    [...]
```

I'm expecting after `magento app:config:import` the path `customer/captch/enable` with value `0` should be added to `core_config_data` table.

But it's not adding/updating expected record.

What's the point of `magento app:config:import` in this case?

Is there a way to import this config except using `magento config:set`?

It's working in the same way for `env.php` as well, unfortunately.

Magento version: `2.2.5`

Comment: Hi, sorry to open this here, but I want to know if you ever found a way to `app:config:import` system array settings?  I have probably about 1500 `system` config settings - the Magento theme I use also import into `/system_config/` section.  All of them are locked (because of config.php), when removing them - defaults are applied.

Comment: Hi @CvRChameleon, if I understood you correctly, are you talking about `app:config:dump`? I was just removing newly added data manually. https://gist.github.com/andkirby/6675e676462899d46f3a1ec478af6aff Sorry, not sure if this that you are talking about =)

Comment: Hi @Kirby, Unfortunately not - `app:config:dump` exports from database into `config.php` whereas `app:config:import` is supposed to import entries into database, but it skips `system_config core_config_data` entries :(  I have around 1500 entries I am still trying to figure out (even created new questions) how to import them into db.

Comment: Basically, I have a new database, want to import them into `db` so that I can remove them from `config.php` so that they are editable in backend of Magento admin.  Very inconvenient system they created with configs.

Answer (score 1):

> Magento directly uses values in the system array in the config.php or env.php files instead of importing them into the database because they require some pre- and post-processing actions.

See official documentation for more details:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html